# How to pronounce "eval"?

Tags: pronunciation

I know this is short for evaluation, as given by an engine, but I don't know how to pronounce it. My guess is simply like the first two syllables of evaluation but I would like to be reassured.

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Comment: You can also hear people pronouncing it on YouTube if you do a search

Comment: this is probably better suited for http://english.stackexchange.com/ (and this [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329151/why-are-the-vowels-in-christ-and-christmas-different-and-other-strange-diphtho/329192#329192) is relevant I think)

Comment: @hkBst This question should be asked and answered here because only chess players are competent, not linguists.

Answer (score 3):

To pronounce "eval" it would be:
[EE-vahl]

Accent the first syllable

Comment: Which syllable is stressed? Is the last syllable like in volleyball?

Comment: I was thinking EE-val

Comment: To fix notation, to me "vahl" sounds like volley while "val" like valley (like pal). So eval would sound like peepal similar to paypal. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You pronounce it like the first part of the word "evaluation".

There's actually an internationally standardized way of writing words phonetically which is employed in most modern dictionaries. Meriam-Webster's dictionary also provides links to audible pronunciations of most words, [including this one](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evaluation).

[image: evaluate]