# How do you pronounce Caissa?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation

I imagine that it might be pronounced:

1. kye EE suh
2. kah EE suh
3. KAY suh
4. KYE suh.

Which is it? Or perhaps there is no established way and one shouldn't care too much.

Comment: Like [this question](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14661/how-to-pronounce-eval), this is probably off-topic because it is about (the English) language.

Comment: You are presumably asking about [Caïssa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%AFssa) (note the [tréma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29) which rules out 3) and 4)). Again better asked on http://english.stackexchange.com/ (and you should improve your question to explain who Caïssa is.

Answer (score 4):

**Short version:**

I think that your best bet is probably option 2: "kah EE suh" (similar to the pronunciation of "naïve"). The phonemes match the spelling correctly (particularly the umlauted ï in "Caïssa" [ref. 1]), and it fits with the tonal stressing of multiple Thracian-related [ref. 2] languages.

---

**Long version:**

Historically, both Greek and and Turkish (largely Hittite and Assyrian influences, in Thracian times [ref.s 3 & 4]) would appear to have likely had the strongest early influences.

Satemization of the Thracian language [ref. 5] would indicate the initial “C” to *typically* be an “s” sound, though it seems that in the case of “Caïssa” it was more likely a “k” sound.

Given the remnants of the Thracian language available to us [ref. 6], there seem to be insufficient data to ensure “correct” pronunciation.  Thracian words seem [to me] to be equally likely to be most closely related to Latin, Greek, and several Balto-Slavic languages.

If Gottfried Schramm's derivation [ref. 7] is correct, then his Bessian-Albanian link would indicate that the “i” is indeed a “long e” (ï) sound [ref. 8].

---

**References:**

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8F
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%AFssa
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thracians
4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey#Prehistory_of_Anatolia_and_Eastern_Thrace
5. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centum_and_satem_languages
6. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thracian_language#Remnants_of_the_Thracian_language
7. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thracian_language#cite_note-3
8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_language#Vowels

Answer (score 1):

[How To Pronounce Caissa](https://www.howtopronounce.com/caissa/) Please listen to all the options to get a sense on how to pronounce casissa.